# Why sqflite didn't work on my android device?

Tags: flutter, sqflite, flutter-release

my app work without any error in the debug mode in the emulator
but in my android physical device the sqflite didn't work how can i fix this
it's there an option i can do before the release or what i searched alot without any sol
this is the most code of the sqflite:

```
class TodoDb {
  RxList<Map>? data;
  static Database? _db;
  RxInt completed=0.obs;

  Future<Database?> get db async{
    if(_db==null){
      _db=await instial();
      return _db;
    }
    return _db;
  }
  instial () async{
    String databasepath=await getDatabasesPath();
    String path= p.join(databasepath, "local.db");
    Database mydb = await openDatabase(path, onCreate: _onCreate, version: 1);
    return mydb;
  }

  _onCreate (Database db, int version)async{
    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE "todo" (
          "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
          "task" TEXT NOT NULL ,
          "icon" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
          "isDone" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
      )
    ''');
    print("ONCREATE ####################################");
  }

  readData()async{
    Database? mydb=await db;
    List<Map> res= await mydb!.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM 'todo'");
    data=res.obs;
    await checkDay();
    return data!.length;
  }

  insertData(String task, int icon)async{
    Database? mydb=await db;
    int response= await mydb!.rawInsert('INSERT INTO todo(task, icon, isDone) VALUES("$task", $icon, false)');
    return response;
  }
}
```

when i connect my phone i get this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such column: false (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO todo(task, ico
n, isDone) VALUES("guy", 57733, false), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'INSERT INTO todo(task, icon, isDone) VALUES("guy", 57733, false)' args []
```

Comment: Is there any log you got while running on the real device?

Comment: how can i check it ?

Comment: check manifest and give permission of storage then it will work

Comment: i added it but i got the error above look at edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bool is not a supported [SQLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#supported-sqlite-types) type. Use INTEGER and 0 and 1 values.
and make sure to install the app after uninstalling older version to create the DB on first run.

```
insertData(String task, int icon)async{
    Database? mydb=await db;
    int isDone = 0; //1 - true , 0 - false
    int response= await mydb!.rawInsert('INSERT INTO todo(task, icon, isDone) VALUES("$task", $icon, $isDone)');
    return response;
  }
```